# User.IsInRole not working when using Google authentication after login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've seen several questions/answers around `User.IsInRole` not working, but all the fixes require things to be done manually. When using Google authentication, everything is just handled for you.

This doesn't work:

```
User.IsInRole( "Admin" )
```

This does work:

```
var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync( User );
var isAdmin = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync( user, "Admin" );
```

What can I do when using Google authentication for the `User.IsInRole` scenario to work?

I follow these 2 docs to get Google authentication working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins

Comment: The method of authentication has no bearing on whether or not a user is in a role. If `IsInRole` is returning false, then the user being identified by the external login *is not in that role*. Plain and simple.

Comment: `User.IsInRole` uses cookies and `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` will hit the db. After logging in, the first will not work, but the second will. The fixes for this traditionally are doing things to make sure that cookie gets set. This things are all handled for you when using `app.UserGoogleAuthentication`, so I don't know what I can do to update the state of my app/cookie, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for benefit of other, I just wasted a full after this. This can happen because of two reasons:

1. If you're using CORE 2.1 app.
2. If you've custom claims, you need to make sure you use role aware claims factory.

[Hope this helps.](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813)